# Printing points in order

Tags: python

I have the following points

```
 (4, 7),(5, 2),(4, 6),(4, 8)
```

I want them to be printed in the order like below without using sort

```
(4, 6)
(4, 7)
(4, 8)
(5, 2)
```

In the original question it says to use built-in function for sorting the values
but is not getting executed by "sorted".
my code is-

```
l=set({})
m=set({})
n=set({})
o=set({})
o1=set({})
o2=set({})
x=set({})
x1=set({})
x2=set({})
y=set({})
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
i=1
while i<=8:
    d=[i,b]
    l.add(tuple(d))
    e=[a,i]
    m.add(tuple(e))
    i=i+1
n=l|m
p=int(input())
q=int(input())
i=1
while i<=8:
    ab=[i,q]
    o.add(tuple(ab))
    cd=[p,i]
    o1.add(tuple(cd))
    i=i+1
i=0
while i<=8:
    de=[p+i,q+i]
    if de[0]>8 or de[1]>8:
        break
    else:
        o2.add(tuple(de))
    i=i+1
i=0
while i<=8:
    ef=[p-i,q-i]
    if ef[0]<1 or ef[1]<1:
        break
    else:
        x.add(tuple(ef))
    i=i+1
i=0
while i<=8:
    gh=[p-i,q+i]
    if gh[0]<1 or gh[1]>8:
        break
    else:
        x1.add(tuple(gh))
    i=i+1
i=0
while i<=8:
    hg=[p+i,q-i]
    if hg[0]>8 or hg[1]<1:
        break
    else:
        x2.add(tuple(hg))
    i=i+1
y=o|o1|o2|x|x1|x2
cs=n&y
from pprint import pprint
final=list(cs)
for i in range(len(final)):
    pprint(final[i])
```

I know its too big.
I am using pprint still not getting the output as mentioned.
The input values are a=4,b=2,p=5,q=7

Comment: Does `list.sort()` count?

Comment: `sorted` returns the sorted list. Either use `sort` to sort in place, or use the return of `sorted`.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid sorted?  Are those tuples in a list?  What's the criteria for correct ordering?  The first value then the second value are  considered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a list of tuples with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643099/sorting-a-list-of-tuples-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: The restrictions are conflicting, first you state "without using 'sorted'", then "use built-in function for sorting the values" - `sorted()` *is* a built-in function, so why can't you use it? Please include the original question verbatim, without paraphrasing, so we can understand the real problem and the restrictions on a solution. thank you.

Comment: @downshift I want the answer without using sorted because the code is not being excecuted with sorted,its a hidden test case

Comment: yes the tuples are in list @RagingRoosevelt

Comment: wait i'll share the question with you guys,it might give clarity

Comment: Given the position of a Rook and a queen in a chess board (8X8 board),  write an algorithm and the subsequent Python code to determine the common positions where both rook and queen can be placed in the next move. Rook can move through any number of cells,  either horizontally or vertically. Queens can move through any number of cells,  either horizontally, vertically or diagonally.  Each cell in the chess board may be represented as a 2-tuple (row,col).

Comment: The output is a set of common board positions where both queen and rook can be placed. The positions must be printed in sorted order, sort it by row. When rows are same,  sort it by column.

Comment: What's the code you have with the `sorted` that is not being executed?

Comment: I have added the code in the question now@franciscosollima

Answer (score 1):

The built-ins `sorted` and `sort` are available and both sort the way I understand you need, first by the first element, and then by the second.

You can either use `sort`, which modifies the points list:

```
points = [(4, 7),(5, 2),(4, 6),(4, 8)]
points.sort()  # Modifies points
print(points)
# outputs [(4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 2)]
```

Or use `sorted`, which outputs a new list ordered:

```
points = [(4, 7),(5, 2),(4, 6),(4, 8)]
points_sorted = sorted(points)  # Creates a new list and saves it as points_sorted
print(points_sorted)
# outputs [(4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 2)]
```

If you need another logic for the ordering, you have to add a parameter to the `sort`/`sorted`, which I can help you with.

Comment: thank you but I can not use sort .It is a hidden test case and won't pass the code